# Printing triangle with given letter in C++

Tags: c++, alphabet

I would like to to print a triangle with a given letter. For example, if I input D, the program should return:

```
     A
     AB
     ABC
     ABCD
```

So far, I have managed to print all letters until the given one in my example, but as you see this method is not quite effective since I need to do this for all 26 cases since the English alphabet is 26 chars. Is there some way to optimize my code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char i;
    cout << "Enter char ";
    cin >> i;
    int c = static_cast<int>(i);
    if (65 < c) {
        cout << "A";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (66 < c) {
        cout << "AB";
        cout << endl;
    }
    if (67 < c) {
        cout << "ABC";
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 64; i < c; i++) {
        cout << static_cast<char>(i + 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use a [while loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_while_loop.htm).

Comment: Use character constants / literals instead of numbers.  For example: if ('A' < c)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need to work on your comprehension of loops. This one works just fine and it even has some checks on what is typed in and it eventually converts lower case letters into upper casse.

```
char first = 'A';
char last = 0;

cout << "Enter a char: ";
cin >> last;
fflush(stdin);
cout << "\n\n";

if ((last > 96) && (last < 123)) //97 to 122 are lower case letters
{
    last -= 32; //32 is the delta between each lower case letter and its upper case "twin"
}

if ((last > 64) && (last < 91))
{
    for (char i = 65; i <= last; i++)
    {
        for (char j = 65; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << j;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "\nWrong character!!\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes you have point this is extremly easy just 2 for cycles , but Im really tired I did before that discrete maths and my head just explode , so I tryed fast to write this code but :). Thank you very much for showing me how easy it is :)

Comment: No need to say you can replace numbers with actual characters, like `last > 96` can be typed as `last >= 'a'`, `i = 65` as `i = 'A'` and so on....

Comment: Also, I declared and initialized the `first` char type variable which then I didnt use. It should've had been placed where you initialize `i` and `j`....or just delete the variable and forget about it, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested loop structure.  Use the outer loop to 'walk' down your triangle,

```
lineLength = 1;
while(lineLength <= (c - 64)){
    ...stuff...

    lineLength++;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Use the inner loop to 'walk' down the alphabet (you've already done most of this):

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
    cout << static_cast<char>(i + 65);
}
```

Putting it together:

```
lineLength = 1;
while(lineLength <= (c - 64)){
    for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++) {
        cout << static_cast<char>(i + 65);
    }

    lineLength++;
    cout << endl;
}
```

I see that someone else has posted a similar answer.  Between these two answers, you should be able to find your way.  I haven't compiled and run this code, but I believe that it should work or be very close.

Comment: There are two other answers that deserve attention, that I would like to acknowledge.  The practice of performing checks and ensuring that everything is the same case is VERY good.  Additionally, the practice of placing hardcoded integers (as I did) into code is definitely frowned upon.  It looks like you have a solid start.

Answer (score 3):

Don't harcode ascii integer values into code.  Explicitly use the character or string literals (e.g. `'A'` instead of `65`)

Start with a helper function to print exactly one line

```
// prints all the characters of the alphabetic sequence from "A" to the final char designated by <c>
void printTriangleLine(char c)
{
    if ((c < 'A') || (c > 'Z'))
    {
        return;
    }

    for (char x = 'A'; x <= c; x++)
    {
        cout << x;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Then put it all together in your main:

```
int main()
{
    char i;
    cout << "Enter char ";
    cin >> i;

    if ((i < 'A') || (i > 'Z'))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for (char x = 'A'; x <= i; x++)
    {
        printTriangleLine(x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We must run the loop from position is above 'A' character
until we reached the charanter you enter

```
    // procead until reached input letter
    while (chNew != c)
    {
             // go to next letter
        chNew++;

             // start with 'A' until current char + 1
        for (int j = 'A'; j < chNew + 1; j++)
            cout << (char)j;
             // go to next line
        cout << endl;
    }
```

in each loop we increment character value by 1 to go to the next value

```
// go to next letter
chNew++;
```

inner loop simply print the character from `A` to next value relative to current `chNew + 1`, it is because we also want to include current character to our printed line.

Here is your working code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char i;
    cout << "Enter char ";
    cin >> i;
    int c = static_cast<int>(i);

    // start with 'A' - 1 character
    char chNew = 'A' - 1;

    // procead until reached input letter
    while (chNew != c)
    {
             // go to next letter
        chNew++;

             // start with 'A' until current char + 1
        for (int j = 'A'; j < chNew + 1; j++)
            cout << (char)j;
             // go to next line
        cout << endl;
    }

    // we have done 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, instead of doing all the work for the OP.

Comment: This is not a forum. The very purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a central repository for programming problems & solutions. You should never simply do the work for other users, you should  *explain* why your solution works.

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-a-description-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-answ?lq=1

Comment: @bob , I still explained myself the code of Mykola is woring perfectly fine I just didn't know I should make it with a while cycle :). But all of you guys helped me a lot thx :)

Comment: This answer is [being discussed on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/are-answers-that-contain-only-commented-code-acceptable).